# Android: ClassCastException:AutoFitTextureView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: android

I am trying to integrate a [Google Sample App](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) into an my own App. [The Sample App](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) illustrates the use of Camera2 API. The sample App compiles and runs just fine.

As said, I would like to use the `CameraActivity.java`, `Camera2BasicFragment.java` and `AutoFitTextureView.java` in my App. However, when I run my App, I get this error:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{openbook.pub.sypa/openbook.pub.sypa.CameraActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: openbook.pub.sypa.AutoFitTextureView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup**

Here is logcat dump:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: openbook.pub.sypa, PID: 28414
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{openbook.pub.sypa/openbook.pub.sypa.CameraActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: openbook.pub.sypa.AutoFitTextureView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2406)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:152)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: openbook.pub.sypa.AutoFitTextureView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
at android.app.BackStackRecord.configureTransitions(BackStackRecord.java:1275)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.beginTransition(BackStackRecord.java:1018)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:748)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1461)
at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2084)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:929)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1076)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1058)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1883)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6038)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:152) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

In this logcat dump, there is no reference to any code that I wrote, so I am not sure where to look...

Here is the fragment layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<openbook.pub.sypa.AutoFitTextureView
    android:id="@+id/texture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/control"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="252dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@color/control_background">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/picture" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_info" />

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have even copied the build.gradle file from the Sample App to my own App., to make sure it depends on the same libraries. I have also cleaned the project.

Why do I get this error? And why does it work fine in Google's Sample App?

Comment: It would appear that you are attempting to cast the `AutoFitTextureView` to a `ViewGroup`. I don't see this happening anywhere in the sample app, so you likely have introduced a typo somewhere.

Comment: In your xml you're using `openbook.pub.sypa.AutoFitTextureView`, but in your fragment you're using `AutoFitTextureView` of your project (`com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView`) . Maybe that's why you get the ClassCastException. Try with the same class in both xml and java code.

Comment: @Rami What makes you say: "but in your fragment you're using AutoFitTextureView of your project (com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView) " ? I believe I am using `pub.openbook.sypa.AutoFitTextureView`

Comment: @IvoRenkema From [your code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java) i can't see any import of *"openbook.pub.sypa.AutoFitTextureView"* so AutoFitTextureView in your fragment should be the one of *"com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView"*